# Binding to new properties in AngularJS directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm confused about how directives work and I have a feeling I'm using them incorrectly.

My goal was to use the directive to show a popup window that has a single text input and submit button.

Clicking the button would fire an ajax POST that would submit the text input value.

What I'm confused about is how and where I define both the model that binds the input and the function that executes it.

I understand I can create the functions and property on the main controller and pass them into the scope variable, but this doesn't make sense to me, because the function is isolated to the directive...

I also don't think I'm supposed to add these to the **scope** variable that comes in the **link** function, because i dont want to manipulate the controller scope, since that seems like a bad idea.

but I don't see any mechanism into which to place my directive model and functions, so is there a different tool I should be using? I want the directive so i can declare it as an element like

```
<my-popup />
```

but I don't know how to give this directive its own scope with its own properties and functions...

am I using this incorrectly or should I be using something else, and most importantly, why?

I hope this is enough info to explain my issue, I'm too new to angular to be able to explain this with a snippet...

thanks

Comment: aha, so it turns out I can add a controller to my directive and use that, this seems perfect, and a likely solution. BUT what if I do want to combine scope properties from the parent controller WITH my directive controller, is that just a matter of defining both scope and controller on the directive?

Answer (score 1):

Directives in Angular can have their own scope, which either inherits from the parent controller scope (using `scope:true`) or have a isolated scope (using `scope:{}`) which is isolated as the name suggest.

If you create a new scope in directive (inherited or isolated), you can attach properties and function on it and it would not affect the parent scope.

This can be done either in the link function or there is a `controller` property that takes a controller function. See the [directive guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more information.

The way data is passed into you directive to depends upon how scope is created. if scope:true is used then the directive scope has access to all data defined on parent scope, whereas if isolated scopes are used you need to pass data using mechanism described in the directive guide. Please go through it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a skeleton of how you can set up your directive, Controller. There may be a few syntax errors.
Note that in the controller you can pass in a service(I called mine dataService) to handle your http calls. A link to the code html code is in the template. This URl is set up through your routing in your config file.

```
app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: ‘/url’,//set up in your routing
    scope{
        variable:”=“ // passed in from parent on directive
    }
    controller: “myController”
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    }
 };
});
app.controller("myController", [       
    “$scope",'dataService',function($scope,dataService) {
    dataService.getCall()
});

<my-popup  variable=“variableFromParent”/>
```